# A fair dice problem

Tags: probability

In a game with one  fair dice, a player wins $20$ dollars if he rolls $2$ (throwing the dice), wins $40$ dollars if he rolls $4$ (throwing the dice) and loses $30$ dollars if he rolls $3$. In any other situation he neither loses nor wins any money.

How much money is he expected to win if he throws the dice once?

Does the result (of the previous question) change if he keeps on throwing the dice until he wins or loses(here we mean that he continues to throw the dice until he rolls $2$ or $4$ or $3$)?

Here I will give my answer to the first question and I'd like some help with the second one please.
So we have :
$Y:$ profit of the player in a game,
I found the average value of $X$
$$E[Y]=\sum^{4}_{i=1}ip(y_{i})=-30 \cdot \frac{1}{6}+0 \cdot \frac{1}{2}+20 \cdot \frac{1}{6}+ 40 \cdot \frac{1}{6}=5$$
Therefore the player is expected to win $ 5$ .

Comment: Do you mean if we rolls a 2,3,4 instead of brings?

Comment: yes I'm sorry , I will fix it

Comment: @george_ioanidis I edited your post with LaTeX, can you please approve it thanks :)

Comment: Thank you , I approved it !!

Comment: @george_ioanidis thanks, also your welcome!

Comment: Your calculations in the first case look fine. Do you have any thoughts on the second one?

Comment: I don"t know what to do.Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

Your first part is correct.

Basically the second part means that you will ignore any throw that isn't a $2,3$, or $4$. So instead of $6$ possible outcomes, there are only $3$.  You can rework the problem the same way based on those new probabilities and compare answers.

Comment: Now i find 10$!  The  player   wins 10 dollars.It is so simple.Thanks.

Comment: Another way of thinking about this, incidentally, is that you're _conditioning_ the expectation on the assertion that the result is one of the 'meaningful' ones, and using one of the simplest forms of conditional expectation.

Comment: Ι am not sure that i understand what do you mean.Could you write with possibilities what do you mean,please.

Comment: @george_ioanidis Consider this:  If he rolls once, he has a (1/2) chance of breaking even, and a (1/2) chance of netting the **average** of $(20 + 40 - 30) = \frac{20 + 40 - 30}{3} = 10.$  In the second scenario, it is **certain** that he will win $\frac{20 + 40 - 30}{3} = 10.$